# Eclipse-plugin: How to add a command at a specific location in a toolbar using menuContribution?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, toolbar

Is there a way to add your command at a specific location in the main toolbar using locationURI ?  What I'd like to achieve is to add my menuContribution after say the (File,Save, SaveAll, Print) so that it remains there and doesn't keep shifting to different positions drastically. I am currently using

```
<menuContribution
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">.
```

This always adds your contributions at the end of the list in the toolbar.

I have tried replacing after=additions with after=print but it doesn't work.

Any inputs or suggestions will be really helpful.

**Thanks**

Comment: What would you expect to happen when multiple plugins want this behavior for the same spots?

Comment: Yeah that is something which needs to be checked, as of now I just have a single plugin which contributes to the Toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [IIDEActionConstants](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/ide/IIDEActionConstants.html) interface. Your locationURI would be `toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.workbench.file?after=build.group`. It's normal for different plugins to contribute to same locations.