# Eclipse plugin - arranging the menuContributions at a specific location

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have multiple plugins added to my menu in eclipse. Can someone please guide me how can I arrange these contributions in a certain way? Eclipse seems to arrange them as per my projects arranged in the package explorer. I referred to this question: 
[Eclipse-plugin: How to add a command at a specific location in a toolbar using menuContribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440522/eclipse-plugin-how-to-add-a-command-at-a-specific-location-in-a-toolbar-using-m)

However, the suggested solution does not work for me. Can someone please give me an example regarding how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out:

I used the id of different plugins for ?after=xxxx. That did the trick of arranging my menuContribution at a desired location.